# Get Fax Job Status

Tags: delphi, winfax

I have tried the code below for sending fax:

```
uses
  ComObj, ActiveX, FAXCOMEXLib_TLB;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  JobIDs: OleVariant;
  FaxServer: IFaxServer2;
  FaxDocument: IFaxDocument2;
begin
  try
    FaxServer := CoFaxServer.Create;
    FaxServer.Connect('');
    FaxDocument := CoFaxDocument.Create;
    FaxDocument.Body := 'd:\Document.pdf';
    FaxDocument.DocumentName := 'Document name';
    FaxDocument.Recipients.Add('+1 (425) 555-4567', 'Bill');
    FaxDocument.Sender.Name := 'Bob';
    FaxDocument.Sender.BillingCode := '23A54';
    FaxDocument.Sender.Department := 'Accts Payable';
    FaxDocument.Sender.FaxNumber := '+972 (4) 555-9070';
    JobIDs := FaxDocument.ConnectedSubmit(FaxServer);

    for I := VarArrayLowBound(JobIDs, 1) to VarArrayHighBound(JobIDs, 1) do
      ShowMessage('Job ID: ' + VarArrayGet(JobIDs, [I]));
  except
    on E: EOleSysError do
      ShowMessage(
        Format('Sending of the fax failed! %s [%d]', [E.Message, E.ErrorCode])
      );
  end;
end;
```

What I was trying to do was get the job status for the fax sent. I have tried to add

```
var
  FaxJobStatus: IFaxJobStatus;
.....

FaxJobStatus := CoFaxJobStatus.Create;
```

compiled the source code and found no error but after executing the code, it fails at 
    FaxJobStatus := CoFaxJobStatus.Create
saying "class not registered".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [IFaxJobStatus documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685966%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> You do not create the FaxJobStatus object. It is received as part of a notification when you implement IFaxServerNotify::OnIncomingJobChanged or IFaxServerNotify::OnOutgoingJobChanged, which include a parameter of the type FaxJobStatus. When the event occurs and the implemented function is called, you receive this object containing the dynamic information.

So you have to register for the `IFaxServerNotify.OnIncomingJobChanged` or `IFaxServerNotify.OnOutgoingJobChanged` events. When the event is received, you get the FaxJobStatus object and can read its `Status` property.

Comment: Thank you for the documentation link. I have read it and the way I understand it I have tried to add FaxServer.ListenToServerEvents(fsetOUT_QUEUE) to the code and created a procedure FaxServer_OnOutgoingJobChanged(FaxServer: IFaxServer; JobId: String; JobStatus: FaxJobStatus) that just returns a message. Now, how do I make this procedure handle the IFaxServerNotify.OnOutgoingJobChanged method?

Comment: It's much more complicated than that, I'm afraid. You need to implement a class to use as a COM Event Sink, and then register for the event using Advise() (and unregister when you're finished using Unadvice, IIRC). Remy Lebeau just demonstrated doing so here (not for a FAXStatus, though). I'll see if I can find a link to that answer.

Comment: Here's a [link to the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24558046) I mentioned by Remy.

Comment: Thanks again for that insight. I found an [even sink documentation](http://www.gekko-software.nl/Delphi/art10.htm). Now the problem is, the faxcomexlib is in faxcomexlib_tlb.pas and not faxcomexlib.tlb. As I understand it, .tlb can be open in the type library. Is there a way to convert .pas into .tlb? or is this question subject to another question post?

Comment: You don't "convert a .pas into a .tlb". You add that `faxcomexlib_tlb.pas` file to your uses clause (just like you would any other Delphi unit), and then you can use the interfaces and classes declared in it within your own code.

Comment: I just figured out the problem. I have been using the IFaxServer instead of the TFaxServer component. Thank you for everything. If not for your answers, I wouldn't have understood automation.

Comment: I was able to invoke the event FOnOutgoingJobChanged(Self, Params[2] {const IFaxJobStatus}, Params[1] {const WideString}, Params[0] {const IFaxServer}) from the FAXCOMEXLIB but then the event procedure from the component of the client side has this variable parameter pJobStatus: OleVariant. Thinking that directly coding pJobStatus.Status would get me the status but then an error occurred stating that method is not under the automation. How do I get the value of this variable?