# Delphi: Retrieve current network connection type

Tags: delphi

I already searched in multiples sites for a routine in Delphi that retrieves the current network connection type (wifi, Ethernet, Bluetooth) but I not have found.

I'm searching for something like this in C# language:

```
 public string TipoConexao()
        {
            string conexao = String.Empty;
            UdpClient u = new UdpClient(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName(), 1);
            IPAddress localAddr = (u.Client.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint).Address;
            NetworkInterface[] netIntrfc = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
            for (int i = 0; i < netIntrfc.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (netIntrfc[i].OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                {
                    IPInterfaceProperties ipProps = netIntrfc[i].GetIPProperties();
                    foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation uni in ipProps.UnicastAddresses)
                    {
                        if (uni.Address.ToString() == localAddr.ToString())
                        {
                            conexao = netIntrfc[i].Name.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return conexao;
        }
```

but in Delphi code.

So, someone here have a routine similar to routine above, in Delphi code?

Comment: Note that your C# example code returns the *last* interface name only in case there is more than one available

Comment: @mjn, the C# example above returns exactly the active type connection. Very good this example! with relation to source code example below left by RRUZ, in your opinion, is possible retrieve only name connection type active?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check these two options.

### WINAPI

To determine the type of the network adapter you can use  the [`GetIfTable2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365945(v=vs.85).aspx) function  which return a [`MIB_IF_TABLE2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366843(v=vs.85).aspx) structure. This record contains an array of [`MIB_IF_ROW2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa814491(v=vs.85).aspx) structures from  here check the value of the `PhysicalMediumType` member.

### WMI

Use the `MSNdis_PhysicalMediumType` WMI class located in the `root\WMI` namespace, the property `NdisPhysicalMediumType` contains the type of the adapter (9 = Wifi, 10 = Bluetooth) , the meaning of these values are the same of the `PhysicalMediumType` of the `MIB_IF_ROW2` structure.

```
uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Variants;



// NDIS Physical Medium Type

procedure  GetMSNdis_PhysicalMediumTypeInfo;
const
  WbemUser            ='';
  WbemPassword        ='';
  WbemComputer        ='localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\WMI', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM MSNdis_PhysicalMediumType','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
    Writeln(Format('InstanceName              %s',[String(FWbemObject.InstanceName)]));// String
    Writeln(Format('NdisPhysicalMediumType    %d',[Integer(FWbemObject.NdisPhysicalMediumType)]));// Uint32

    Writeln('');
    FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;


begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      GetMSNdis_PhysicalMediumTypeInfo;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

---

Note : for both solutions the minimum OS version supported is Windows Vista.

## Update

This is a full sample which return the connection type of the connected adapters. The *NETWORKLIST_TLB* unit is generated by the Delphi IDE when you import the `Network List 1.0 Type Library`.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Windows,
  NETWORKLIST_TLB in 'NETWORKLIST_TLB.pas';


function  GetAdapterDescription(const Guid : string) : string;
const
  WbemUser            ='';
  WbemPassword        ='';
  WbemComputer        ='localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
begin;
  Result:='';
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\CIMV2', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery(Format('SELECT Description FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter Where GUID=%s', [QuotedStr(Guid)]), 'WQL', wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  if oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 then
    Result:=  String(FWbemObject.Description);
end;

function  GetMSNdis_PhysicalMediumType(const Adapter : string) : Uint32;
const
  WbemUser            ='';
  WbemPassword        ='';
  WbemComputer        ='localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
begin;
  Result:= 0;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\WMI', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery(Format('SELECT NdisPhysicalMediumType FROM MSNdis_PhysicalMediumType Where InstanceName = %s', [QuotedStr(Adapter)]), 'WQL', wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  if oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 then
    Result :=  FWbemObject.NdisPhysicalMediumType;
end;


procedure GetNetworkInfo;
var
  NetworkListManager: INetworkListManager;
  EnumNetworksConnections: IEnumNetworkConnections;
  Network: INetwork;
  NetworkConnection : INetworkConnection;

  fetched: ULONG;
  AdapterGUID,  AdapterDesc : string;
  PhysicalMediumType : Uint32;
begin
   NetworkListManager := CoNetworkListManager.Create;
   EnumNetworksConnections :=  NetworkListManager.GetNetworkConnections;
   while true do
   begin
     EnumNetworksConnections.Next(1, NetworkConnection, fetched);
     if (fetched>0) and (NetworkConnection.IsConnectedToInternet) then
     begin
       Network :=  NetworkConnection.GetNetwork();
       WriteLn('Connection Name ' + Network.GetName);
       AdapterGUID := GUIDToString(NetworkConnection.GetAdapterId);
       AdapterDesc := GetAdapterDescription(AdapterGUID);
       Writeln('Adapter  GUID   ' + AdapterGUID);
       Writeln('Adapter         ' + AdapterDesc);
       PhysicalMediumType := GetMSNdis_PhysicalMediumType(AdapterDesc);

        //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa814491(v=vs.85).aspx
        case PhysicalMediumType of
          9  :   Writeln('Connection Type Wifi');
          10 :   Writeln('Connection Type Bluetooth');
        else
                 Writeln('Connection Type '+IntToStr(PhysicalMediumType));
        end;
     end
     else
     Break;
   end;
end;

begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      GetNetworkInfo;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

Comment: OK @RRUZ, now how retrieve only of connected adapter to internet?

Comment: Try the [`GetBestInterface`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365920(VS.85).aspx) or the [`INetworkConnection.GetConnectivity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370758(v=vs.85).aspx) method.

Comment: You could give me a example using the your code above please?

Comment: I'm Sorry, but you must put some effort on this too and try to build the solution using the answer provided and my comments. Also if you have another problem you can ask another question.

Comment: I not found any reference about using the `WMI` class together with `INetworkConnection::GetConnectivity` method for example.

Comment: That is the developer job, put things together and create something new.

Comment: I found this example http://pastebin.com/jYrfMMZV in C++ using INetworkConnection::GetConnectivity, but how use the your code above passing some adapter as parameter for this function?

Comment: give me a example based on your code above please, it will be util for other users that are needing also and not only for me. I found this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553706/register-for-nlm-events-inetworklistmanager-advise-sink-etc that have the unit necessary for work with `INetworkListManager::GetConnectivity`

Comment: Your sample code is using the `INetworkListManager::GetConnectivity` function, instead you must use the `INetworkConnection::GetConnectivity` from here you must correlate the propeties on this way `MSNdis_PhysicalMediumType.InstanceName` = `Win32_NetworkAdapter.Description` -> `Win32_NetworkAdapter.GUID` = `INetworkConnection.GetAdapterId`